# git completion runs cTest

Tags: git, bash-completion, ctest

I am in a weird situation under Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (using bash) :

I installed git via apt-get and everything works fine. However, when I want to autocomplete commands via git (I did not do anything for this to work, it is just a reflex to hit tab all the time), cTest starts.

It is strange as hell and I don't get how this can happen. Of course, cTest finds nothing and tells me that "No tests were found !!!".

Does anyone has an idea about how to fix this ?

Comment: You did not state which shell you are using

Comment: My bad, I use bash. I completed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a [related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210291/git-autocomplete-is-asking-for-a-password-not-sure-why/213779#213779?newreg=afc71e4c3f9f46ce993570784f8d2a33) answering my question.
In short, the git version coming with ubuntu, starting from version 12.10, actually contains and/or calls a `test` function. Having a `test` alias in the `.bashrc` file redirects the call to that alias.

However, the reason why hitting Tab while writing a git command triggered any kind of `test` function remains unknown.